# Как через CSS убрать полупрозрачный тёмный прямоугольник при нажатии пальцем на элемент на мобильных устройствах?

Tags: html, css, css3

При нажатии на ссылку, на мобильных устройствах, на сотни миллисекунд появляется полупрозрачный тёмный прямоугольник на нажатой ссылке, надо через CSS убрать полупрозрачный тёмный прямоугольник

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Предполагаю что нужно сбросить стили для состояния active. Отредактируй свой вопрос и добавь код класса css для этой ссылки. Нажми ctrl + shift + c в браузере и наведи на эту ссылки и справа скопируй код (ну на всякий случай уточнил, вдруг не знаешь).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для удаления полупрозрачного тёмного прямоугольника при нажатии пальцем на элемент на мобильных устройствах, используется CSS-параметр `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);`